# Will the RL agent implemented as a neural network fine-tune itself?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, game-ai, rewards

Normally, when you develop a neural network, train it for object recognition (on normal objects like bike, car, plane, dog, cloud, etc.), and it turns out to perform very well, you would like to fine-tune it for e.g. recognizing dog breeds, and this is called fine-tuning.

On the other hand, in reinforcement learning, let's consider a game with rewards on checkpoints $1, 2, 3, \dots n$. When you have a bot that plays and learns using some (e.g. value) neural net, it develops some style of solving the problem to reach some checkpoint $k$, and, after that, when it will reach the $k+1$ checkpoint, it probably will have to revalue the whole strategy.

In this situation, will the bot fine-tune itself? Does it makes sense to keep a replay buffer as is and to "reset" the neural net to train it from scratch, or it's better to stay with fine-tune approach?

If possible, topic-related papers would be very welcome!